# pandas grouby and select value based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

```
df['relativeScore'] = df['score'] - df.groupby(['type'])['score'].transform('max')
```

I've been creating a new column (relativeScore) based on a column (`score`) minus the largest `score` seen per a given category (`type`).

I'd like to change this so that rather than picking the largest score (via `.transform("max")` I pick this value based on another column (specifically, when `selected` is equal to `yes`).

In my naive mind, it should look something like:

`df['relativeScore'] = df['score'] - df.groupby(['type'])['score'].selected=="yes"`

I have tried a subselect, then a groupby:

`df['relativeScore'] = df['score'] df[df['selected']=="yes"].groupby('type')['score']`

but I get:

```
ValueError: Length of values (7751) does not match length of index (77510)
```

Comment: Thanks @AnuragDabas! I get an error:
```ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (77510,) (7751,2)```

Comment: Hmmm. `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (7751,) (7751,2)`

Comment: try `df.loc[df['selected']=="yes",'relativeScore'] = df.loc[df['selected']=="yes",'score']- df[df['selected']=="yes"].groupby('type')['score'].transform('max')`

Comment: Victory! Thank you :)

Comment: if it works then for simplicity create a boolean mask `m=df['selected']=="yes"` now finally:  `df.loc[m,'relativeScore'] = df.loc[m,'score']- df[m].groupby('type')['score'].transform('max')`

Comment: I spoke too soon. What I'm seeing is a lot of `NaN`'s for rows that are not selected, and then `0` (as we'd expect) for rows that are selected.

Comment: can you post the output of `df.head(10).to_dict()`